# XAML classless attached properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have several attached properties in several classes throughout my framework. All of these are mapped into a single xml Namespace using the `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute`. I have noticed that if I declare some of these attached properties without referring to the class name (the class that actually contains the property, I get the compile-time error:

`The property 'XXX' does not exist in XML namespace 'YYY'`

To explain better, this happens when I have let's say a `FocusHelper` class that has an `IsFocused` attached property, but try to use it in XAML like this:

`<CheckBox my:IsFocused="true"/>`.

Notice I specified the xml namespace (which I have correctly declared), but not the class name.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to achieve this? the error hints me that there is a way to define `properties inside namespaces directly`. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a XAML issue, this is a C# "issue". Meaning, you can't have a "global" property in C#. It must be inside a class.

There is no "global" concept in C#.

In order to get the syntax you want you would have to be able to declare a property globally (i.e. outside the context of a class) and that isn't possible in C#

This is why framework attached properties also have the class name preceding them (Grid.Column, Canvas.Top)

In the case of the Framework Attached properties (Grid.Column, Canvas.Top etc...) you don't have to specify the namespace because they are in the "default" namespace

```
xmlns=""
```

as opposed to your namespace

```
xmlns:my=""
```

Comment: I do understand this. However it could be possible since the mappings between CLR and XAML are performed by the XAML parser. Which is able to translate xmlnses to CLR namespaces by the use of assembly-level attribute. I was just curious if there was some kind of functionality in the WPF xaml parser that could enable this.

Comment: Translating the namespaces doesn't have anything to do with it. How would the parser now what the IsFocused property is? You can't have a loose property in C#, period. So while you are correct, the parser can map multiple CLR namespaces into one XAML namespace through the assembly attribute it doesn't change that fact that properties MUST be contained in a class. I think you are asking two different questions? or I am misunderstanding what you are asking.

Comment: The same way CLR namespaces are mapped using `[XmlnsDefinition(...)]`, you could have, I don't know, `[XmlnsProperty(...)]` to apply to properties. That's how the parser would know what property the string `my:IsFocused` would be mapped to. Would be great for XAML syntax.

Comment: I see, yeah not possible. I disagree on this being "great for XAML syntax" it would be confusing IMO. Without an owning class qualifier, it would be hard to know where the attached property was coming from. This would lead to confusion.  You could accomplish something like this with a custom markup extension if you wanted to really have something syntactically close